# Selenium 4.11.2 with ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniummanager

I'm trying to run this simple code.. But I get a error that I can not fix.
Can someone help me ?

Chrome driver is installed I check:

```
pi@Rpi:~ $ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.98 (564abd8de2c05f45308eec14f9110a10aff40ad9-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1501})
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 123, in run
    completed_proc = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 90, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 129, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}") from err
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome --output json


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/src/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    keep_alive,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I tried reinstalling selenium couple of times. I also tried reinstalling webdriver. Tried to locate the path. But I read it is not necessary anymore. I put the Chromedriver in the Same directory as the Python project

Snapshot of project + Chromedriver:

[image: Place of project + Chromedrive]

Comment: In Python you will need to use the Service class to indicate where you have the chromedriver installed. You then pass a reference to the Service class to Chrome constructor. It is important to note that the version of chromedriver **must** match the version of the Chrome browser you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I put the Chromedriver in the Same directory as the Python project

As you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.11.2*** you don't need to explicitly download [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) or any browser drivers or even need use [*webdriver_manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) any more. You just need to ensure that the desired browser client i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) is installed.

---

### [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

[Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795080/7429447) is the new tool integrated with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) that would help to get a working environment to run Selenium out of the box. Beta 1 of [*Selenium Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691426/7429447) will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc, browser clients, if they are not present on the *`PATH`*.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can simply do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

### tl; dr

[Chrome for Testing: reliable downloads for browser automation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got Chrome(I mean the one with GUI) installed on your computer?The chromedriver is just a **driver**. Please install Chrome Browser and the chormedriver of corresponding version.

Comment: Yes my is not headles. so i can open chromium from the "aplication"menu

Comment: If i Run THIS: 

/usr/bin/chromedriver 

Result:
pi@Rpi:~ $ /usr/bin/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.98 (564abd8de2c05f45308eec14f9110a10aff40ad9-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1501}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.


So i think install is good.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure the version of Webdriver is consistent with or closest to the version of the web.
2.Put the Webdriver in your python root directory

Comment: you mean the project root or python 3.7 install root ?

Comment: Chromiun web browser is: 
Versie 92.0.4515.98 (Officiële build) Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10 (32-bits)
chromium-chromedriver 
 (92.0.4515.98~buster-rpt2).

Comment: /lib/python3.7  Put the chromedriver here ?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
service = ChromeService(executable_path="your_dir_path/chromedriver.exe_")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("url")