# I have two identical projects but I can run Selenium webdriver in only one of them

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am learnig Selenium and I encountered a problem where one of my projects can lanuch a browser but the other one throws errors. Both of them have the same code right now, bot have the webdriver copied to project folder. If I leave this line like it is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I get the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'
> executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
> https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

If I change it to this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Sel\chromedriver.exe")
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at
> 0x0000022461CC8720>, but it must be an int, float or None.

I don't understand why is it happening, both of these projects are the same, configured in the same name, the only difference. So far the whole code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Sel\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

**Update**

I am 100% sure I am using latest Selenium, as per the image below, [as per this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkz2Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same error yesterday.  If it is the same, I was able to fix it by directly editing `Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py`

Replace the 3 occurrences of `_timeout = socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`

with `_timeout = urllib3.util.timeout._DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`

I think it's related to this bug in Jenkins
https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-jenkins/+bug/2018567

This was in v3.141, but I can see the code for setting the default timeout within that module hasn't changed in v4.

See also

- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11988
- https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/2792

Comment: Oh my Zeus, this helped! I still don't get it why one of my projects worked fine, and the other one required me to make changes to Python packages.... I just have to keep my fingers crossed it will never happen again, lol

Comment: Another way is to add socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=urllib3.util.timeout._DEFAULT_TIMEOUT to the top of remote_connection.py (under the imports) to monkeypatch selenium.

This is rather frusturating that its not fixed upstream. This error has been around for quite some time it seems, and its a showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using older version of Selenium. Upgrade to the latest version of selenium(`4.11.0`), then you don't have to specify the path of `chromedriver.exe`. Selenium will internally download and manage the drivers for you.

Code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

For more infor, few useful answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76564551/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

**UPDATE:** If you are using latest selenium, then below line is not correct:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Sel\chromedriver.exe")
```

You need to use [Service class](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/) to configure the driver path, as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Sel/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: I am using Selenium 4.11.2 in both projects. As I've said - they are configured in exactly the same way. Same Python, same PyCharm, same Selenium, same machine, same webdriver, same browser.

Comment: Your edit gives me the following error:

'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Exc\venv\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

'

And it still doesn't explain why these two projects work differently if everything is identical.

Comment: Am mostly certain the selenium running in your project is not `4.11.2`. Can you double check the version? In PyCharm, go to Python Interpreter and check Selenium's version. Share the screenshot of it to your question.

Comment: I checked it again and yes, this is the latest Selenium. Image is in the OP now.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkz2Z.png) as you are on [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.11.2*** you no more need to pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) binary, as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691426/7429447) being fully integrated is invoked transparently by the Selenium bindings when no browser driver is detected on the PATH or no third party driver manager is being used.

You just need to ensure that:

- The *ChromeDriver* is removed from the path:

  ```
  C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Sel\
  ```
- The system *PATH* variable doesn't contains the following entry:

  ```
  C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Sel\
  ```

and you can simply use the line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: Tried that, removing project address from PATH variable results in following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH