# Selenium webdriver is not working in Python. (chromedriver 115.0.5790.171)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have previous selenium experiences in Python but I haven't used it for a long time. 2 days ago I formatted my computer and downloaded all my files again. I will write an automation system for a website via selenium in Python but I am facing a problem that I can't understand right now. My Chrome version is 115.0.5790.171. When I looked at the chromedriver internet update, I saw that the only stable version is 115.0.5790.170. When I try to run it with this, I get an error. Can you help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strange. I tried searching for any chromedriver 115.x and could not find any on the web. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why and how it works but it worked when I assigned the driver variable as follows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It has a bug, which have not been fixed yet.

you have to use 114 version.

Comment: 114 chromedriver doesnt work for 115 chrome if u say this for chrome version how can I do that ?

Comment: No it does not, you need to install an older version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium `4.11.2` has full support for using chromedriver 115 - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/commit/c3b226cebff8caf4fdbc792b87f2de23f42dab3a

It's likely that you have an older version of selenium installed. Once you upgrade, this should work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

[image: error]

...implies that [Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691426/7429447) was unable to obtain [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) for Chrome.

---

### Solution

Possibly you are using an initial version of [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4).

Upgrade [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) to [latest version](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) of ***4.11.2***, so [Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795080/7429447) can automatically download the latest version of *ChromeDriver* i.e. ***v115.x*** for the test execution.

---

### tl; dr

[[rust] Use CfT endpoints to discover chromedriver 115+](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/12208)