# Which version of chrome driver does `webdriver.Chrome()` get in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver, version

I know that `webdriver.Chrome()` below can get the chrome driver but I do not know which version of chrome driver it gets because [the doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) doesn't have any such explanation. *I use **Selenium 4.11.2**:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

So, which version of chrome driver does `webdriver.Chrome()` get? The latest one?

Comment: the doc https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have selenium `4.11.2` or newer installed, calling `webdriver.Chrome()` is going to check if any existing chromedriver on your PATH matches your version of Chrome. If not, it will automatically download the correct driver version for you to `~/.cache/selenium`.

There's a blog post on it here: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/

The Chromium Team recently restructured driver downloads for the new Chrome-for-Testing, (see https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/). The latest version of Selenium is built to handle the latest drivers for that.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, it will be the same version as the browser on your system. For example, if chrome browser in your system is `v114`, then `chromedriver.exe`'s version will be `114`. Check the documentation below:

[image]

[What's new in Selenium Manager with Selenium 4.11.0](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/)

If you are on selenium version `4.11.0` or above, go to below location in your machine, delete all the `chromedriver.exe` from `chromedriver` folder, then run your code. You will see the driver programmatically getting downloaded based on your browser in this location. Now you know which version of driver was being used to run your code.

[image]