# TypeError: WebDriver._init_() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, typeerror, selenium4

I'm here to resolve my issue in the line:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver/chromedriver" options-driverop)
```

shows:

```
TypeError: WebDriver._init_() got multiple values for argument 'options'.
```

I'm using a scraper developed by a developer but now I wanted to set it up on an RDP after setting it up It's having the above error.

While it's running smoothly on my computer I tried downgrading selenium driver but it was not working too. How can my problem be resolved?

Comment: your code formatting is incorrect... I can't quite understand the driver line. Please update your question with improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

From the [Commits in selenium-4.10.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e):

[image: executable_path]

`executable_path` which was deprecated earlier is completely removed now from [***selenium-4.10.0***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-4.10.0) through the merge [Remove deprecated code in driver classes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/12030)

If you look at the [constructor](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-5a60156e0c8a7c920aa161d26581ca3461625b9ea29c059bae02999fd388f22fL39) after *`self`*, the next argument is *`options`* followed by *`service`*.

So when you mention:

```
driver webdriver. Chrome ("chromedriver/chromedriver" options-driverop)
```

at first *`options`* is assigned `"chromedriver/chromedriver"` and then again assigned `options-driverop`. Hence the error.

---

### Solution

Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you have to use the key *`Service()`* . So you need to change as follows:

```
s = Service('chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options-driverop)
```

---

Incase you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above you don't have to explicitly use the *`Service()`* either as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options-driverop)
```