# "disconnected: not connected to DevTools" error in Selenium with Chrome WebDriver at VPN

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

I am encountering a "disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer" error while using Selenium with Chrome WebDriver.
The issue occurs after connecting to a VPN and attempting to open a web page with WebDriver. 
I need to start the WebDriver before connecting to the VPN.

Fetching a web page before VPN connection works fine.
I have tried various solutions, including adjusting ChromeOptions, but the error persists.
Could anyone please provide insights or solutions to resolve this issue? Thank you.

```
import subprocess
import time

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)

subprocess.Popen(
    'rasdial "jp-free-09.protonvpn.net"',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True
)
print('Connected to VPN.')

time.sleep(10)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
driver.quit()
print('Completed.')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\****\****\****\****\****.py", line 23, in <module>
    driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 355, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.102)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A5A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x009EC4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x008F5358]
        (No symbol) [0x008E7D96]
        (No symbol) [0x008E7AB9]
        (No symbol) [0x008F67C0]
        (No symbol) [0x0094C4D8]
        (No symbol) [0x0093A536]
        (No symbol) [0x009182DC]
        (No symbol) [0x009193DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CBAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CFA78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CF456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00AE51E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x009F5F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x009F2328]
        (No symbol) [0x009F240B]
        (No symbol) [0x009E4FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x779200C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C87B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C87AEE+238]
```

Python: 3.11.4
selenium: 4.10.0
webdriver-manager: 3.8.6
Chrome: 115.0.5790.102 (matching ChromeDriver version)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following *arguments* added through the instance of `webdriver.ChromeOptions()` unless mandatory:

- *`--disable-gpu`*
- *`--no-sandbox`*
- *`--disable-dev-shm-usage`*
- *`--disable-software-rasterizer`*
- *`ignore-certificate-errors`*
- *`--remote-debugging-port=9222`*

Further, if you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above you don't have to explicitly use [ChromeDriverManager().install()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) anymore as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447)

---

### Solution

Your minimal code block can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: Thank you, webdriver.ChromeOptions() was added to explicitly state that I had tried to solve the problem, but you are correct.
Also, the implicit installation of ChromeDriverManager().install() was new to me.
I have modified the code based on the above.
However, "disconnected: not connected to DevTools" issue still seems to occur.

Comment: I have added the Traceback code, is this ok? Please check.