# Selenium chrome driver error on Docker Container

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.11

in my local test the code is perfectly worked
but when i build the docker, after run a docker image,

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255"
```

is occured

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY elasticModule.py /app/elasticModule.py
COPY slackMessage.py /app/slackMessage.py
COPY elasticMain.py /app/elasticMain.py
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "elasticMain.py"]
```

and also this is my make webdriver code

```
options = Options()   
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)    
    
driver.get(url)
```

somebody help..

i already try lot's of things.. but it's not work on docker container

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
```

...implies that *WebDriverException* was raised as chromedriver unexpectedly exited.

As per the discussion [Message: Service /root/.local/share/undetected_chromedriver/ae9b10e548ec168c_chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/790) this error can surface if the platform is [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) and machine is ***aarch64*** to indicate additional configuration and installs outside this package is required.

---

### Solution

The easiest solution would be to download the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) yourself from [ChromeDriver-Downloads](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0) and pass the location through an instance of the `Service` object as follows:

```
options = Options()   
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/path/to/chromedriver'), options=options)    
driver.get(url)
```

Further, if you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above you don't have to explicitly use [ChromeDriverManager().install()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) anymore as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and your minimal code block can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: thanks for help. but when i changed the code what you suggest
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
like this
[Errno 86] Bad CPU type in executable: '/Users/hanhyeonbin/Desktop/Automation/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/macos/selenium-manager' 
this error is occured