# Without copying chromedriver.exe manually, selenium-python script is working, is it not mandatory to copy it manually?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I am not copying chromedriver.exe manually but still script is working fine.

But, install steps says that copying chromedriver.exe is required and mandatory.

Is it optional in recent builds ? If not, how script is passing without copying this .exe?

1. Cleared cache (before this deleted previous pycharm project folder), **Windows 10 OS**
2. Installed **Python 3.11.3**
3. Installed **Pycharm community edition b 2023.1.3 231.9161.41**
4. Launched pycharm terminal. (it showed (env) .. prompt automatically.
5. here ran `pip install selenium`, it passed
6. closed and relaunched Pycharm
7. tried following selenium-python script and its passing

   ```
   import time
   from selenium import webdriver
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
   time.sleep(5)
   driver.close()
   ```

**Query**: when `chromedriver.exe` is not copied manually (which is MUST), how script is passing and from where its getting `chromedriver.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. If you are using Selenium `v4.6.0` or above, setting up the path of `chromedriver.exe` is not mandatory anymore.

New in-built tool in the selenium known as `SeleniumManager` will download and handle the browser drivers for you. However, if you want to use a specific `chromedriver.exe` for any reason, you can set the path and that `driver` will be used, if not Selenium will download and handle the `driver.exe` for you.

**References:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574264/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. This solved my puzzle. For Selenium prior to v4.6.0, please guide me for any stackoverflow post that explains the steps needed to configure. (e.g.copying the driver.exe manually.)

Answer (score 1):

With the in introduction of [**Selenium Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above you don't need to explicitly download [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) or any browser drivers as such.

You just need to ensure that the desired browser client i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) is installed. [***Selenium Manager***](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) is the new tool that would help to get a working environment to run Selenium out of the box. ***Beta 1*** of [*Selenium Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76555236/7429447) will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the *`PATH`*.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can simply do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver is in the PATH?

Might help (says that the path is Optional argument):
[https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started]

Answer (score 0):

A template you can use, if you want to maximize the window.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
# pip install webdriver_manager 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
             options=options)
```

Link for Webdriver Manager: [here](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

With the new Selenium Manager, drivers will be automatically downloaded to the `~/.cache/selenium` folder [unless any of these conditions are met](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/1ec3485ecc4af4ada861d6598d29d04b6f9563f5/website_and_docs/content/documentation/selenium_manager.en.md?plain=1#L21):

- The driver location isn't specified in a `Service` class
- A 3rd party driver manager is not installed
- No drivers exist in directories included in the `PATH` Environment Variable

So a command such as `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` does all the work for you now. If you still **want to choose the location**, you can pass in an `executable_path` into the `service` arg, like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```