# i can't install the driver in the location specified by python's webdriver-manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

When I updated webdriver-manager to the latest version (4.0.0), I couldn't install it to the specified location that I could do before.

・before
selenium==3.141.0
webdriver-manager==2.5.2

```
install_path = 'My custom path'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(path=install_path).install())
```

Previously it was working fine in this environment.
However, after updating webdriver-manager to 4.0.0, the following error occurred.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(path=install_path))
TypeError: install() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
```

It seems that the argument (path) that could be specified before has disappeared.
It's not even mentioned in the documentation (https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager).

How can I specify where to install the driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from following [issue](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/584)
you should replace old with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.driver_cache import DriverCacheManager

install_path = 'My custom path'
cache_manager=DriverCacheManager(install_path )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(cache_manager=cache_manager).install()))
```

Comment: I was able to install to the specified path by this procedure.
thank you!

Comment: Great solution. Works perfectly for Chorme, Firefox and Edge

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(path=install_path))
TypeError: install() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
```

...implies that an incorrect keyword was passed to `install()`.

You saw it right. The key `path=install_path` is now removed from the current [**webdriver-manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) release of version ***v4.0.0***.

---

### Solution

You can upgrade to latest release of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.11.2*** as you won't need to explicitly download [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) or any browser drivers as such using [*webdriver_manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447). You just need to ensure that the desired browser client i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) is installed.

[Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) is the new tool integrated with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) that would help to get a working environment to run Selenium out of the box. Beta 1 of [*Selenium Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76555236/7429447) will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the *`PATH`*.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can simply do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

### References

Some useful lins and documentations:

- [webdriver_manager-GitHub](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager)
- [No such driver version 115.0.5790.110 for linux64 error using ChromeDriverManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795080/7429447)
- [selenium-pypi](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)
- [There is no such driver by URL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115.0.5790 error with Python webdrivermanager & Chrome 115.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76725006/7429447)
- [Chrome for Testing: reliable downloads for browser automation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/)

Comment: I didn't know that the latest version of Selenium has such a feature.
It was helpful.

In my case, I needed to use Selenium3, so I chose another answer as the best answer.
thank you very much.