# Selenium + Python + Ubuntu does not work when using sudo

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I configured the OS and it works with sudo or with the root user, but when I try to use it without sudo it gives an error.

Exit without sudo:

`$ python3 test.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maicon/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x563288fa9f83 <unknown>
#1 0x563288c62cf7 <unknown>
#2 0x563288c9a60e <unknown>
#3 0x563288c9726e <unknown>
#4 0x563288ce780c <unknown>
#5 0x563288cdbe53 <unknown>
#6 0x563288ca3dd4 <unknown>
#7 0x563288ca51de <unknown>
#8 0x563288f6e531 <unknown>
#9 0x563288f72455 <unknown>
#10 0x563288f5af55 <unknown>
#11 0x563288f730ef <unknown>
#12 0x563288f3e99f <unknown>
#13 0x563288f97008 <unknown>
#14 0x563288f971d7 <unknown>
#15 0x563288fa9124 <unknown>
#16 0x7f1ef3337ac3 <unknown>
```

Exit with sudo:

`$ sudo python3 test.py`

```
Welcome to Python.org
```

Script used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://python.org")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

These are the output I'm getting with and without sudo permission, and the script I'm trying to run.

Thank you for everyone's help.

Comment: i think with no sudo, does not have permission to install at default location `ChromeDriverManager().install()`try to install with path - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885954/i-cant-install-the-driver-in-the-location-specified-by-pythons-webdriver-manag

Comment: Yes, my chrome version is 120.0.6099.216 and for this version, still don't have the correct chromedrive, you need to use ChromeDriverManager, it's not possible to install the correct driver and that's why it gives this error, I believe.