# Error : "There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116.0.5845"

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

*emphasized text*I am using the library pyhtml2pdf to create a pdf from an html in python. The code was working properly a month ago, but now when I ru it this error appears :

"File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 15, in validate_response
raise ValueError(f"There is no such driver by url {resp.url}")
There is no such driver by url [https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116.0.5845"](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116.0.5845%22)

Here is my code, but I haven't touch it since :

```
from pyhtml2pdf import converter
root = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Directory\\'
converter.convert(root+'html.html', root+'test.pdf')
```

I have checked my browser version of Chrome : "Version 116.0.5845.97 (Build officiel) (64 bits)"
I am also using Avast Secure Browser with this version : "Version 115.0.21984.171 (Build officiel) (64 bits)"

They are both marked as up to date.

I have also tried to follow this question :
[There is no such driver by URL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115.0.5790 error with Python webdrivermanager & Chrome 115.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724939/there-is-no-such-driver-by-url-https-chromedriver-storage-googleapis-com-lates)

I changed some parameters in the file http.py of the webdriver_manager package, but I am not sure to understand how to adapt it to my problem and I don't want to mess with a package I don't really know.