# Can't use Chromedriver 116 with WebDriverManager

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my selenium Java application I have used io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager to automatically use the correct version of chrome driver. I have Chrome version 116. When I run my code it fails with

> Exception reading
> https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116 to get
> latest version of chromedriver (Error HTTP 404 executing
> https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116)
> 2023-09-08 14:31:15,075 INFO
> [com.discordlistener.infiniteoptions.ammar.AmmarAlertsReaderApplication.main()]
> io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager: Exporting
> webdriver.chrome.driver as
> /usr/local/home/kannanj/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver

Indeed https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE only points to 114, so I  went to https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable and downloaded the chromedriver for version 116 and installed it but it didn't make any difference when I ran my application. I even tried after manually copying the 116 version of the driver to /usr/local/home/kannanj/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chromedriver and yet nothing.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76951429/7598774 Or this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774