# Unable to download chrome driver for version 115

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to download the Chrome driver for Chrome version 115. I have downloaded the ZIP file from:

https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.102/win64/chrome-win64.zip

But I am unable to find the `chromedriver.exe` file there.

I am running a Java-Selenium test which needs the `chromedriver` path. I copied the path of `chrome.exe` into the program, but it's failing and giving the error as `Timed out waiting for driver server to start`. Do I need `chromedriver.exe` for this? And how can I get this?

Comment: Looks like you downloaded Chrome (browser) zip and not the [chromedriver](https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.102/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip) one.  I got caught for this as well.

Comment: This helped me -> Webdrivers trying to load a Chrome version that doesn't exist #247   https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/issues/247

Comment: How reputable is `edgedl.me.gvt1.com`?

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Answer (score 12):

Use chrome driver version 114.0.5735.90 for chrome version 115. It's working for me.

Comment: this is the easiest fix. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Use the new *chromedriver* download site:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

The URL under *chromedriver* for win32 holds a *chromedriver.exe* which you have to unpack and add to your path. Both *chromedriver* and Google Chrome of the same version (115) must be found in path by Selenium to work.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case, someone is downloading programmatically in Docker.

So I had a situation, where

- I had latest chrome stable in my Dockerfile
- Using the major version from the *google-chrome*, I had to find out the right URL to use for downloading its corresponding *chromedriver*. Earlier you could use the link `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION}` to get the latest full version, and then it was straightforward to download when you have the full version.

Now, I am using the JSON APIs from the suggested *chrome-for-testing* repository, and finding the URL in it using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to match for major version and platform.

```
curl --silent "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json" \
  | jq --arg majorVersion "$CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION" -r '.channels.Stable | select(.version | startswith($majorVersion | tostring)).downloads.chromedriver[] | select(.platform == "linux64") | .url' \
  | xargs curl -L --show-error --silent --output chromedriver-linux64.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link to the chromedriver for 115 version: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.102/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip

Answer (score 3):

The solution is really easy for this one. **Use Selenium 4.10.0**.

We were using WebDriverManager for driver management and since Chrome updated to version 115, WebDriverManager was unable to find the new *chromedriver* due to the change in the URL.

We simply removed WebDriverManager and let Selenium Manager handle the drivers, and it is now working perfectly fine.

One thing to note is that Selenium is downloading *chromedriver* 114 for Chrome 115. But at least we are not blocked anymore.

Answer (score 3):

To install the latest Chrome and Chromedriver in Docker:

```
# Install latest Chrome
RUN CHROME_URL=$(curl -s https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json | jq -r '.channels.Stable.downloads.chrome[] | select(.platform == "linux64") | .url') \
    && curl -sSLf --retry 3 --output /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip "$CHROME_URL" \
    && unzip /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip -d /opt \
    && ln -s /opt/chrome-linux64/chrome /usr/local/bin/chrome \
    && rm /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip

# Install latest chromedriver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_URL=$(curl -s https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json | jq -r '.channels.Stable.downloads.chromedriver[] | select(.platform == "linux64") | .url') \
    && curl -sSLf --retry 3 --output /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip "$CHROMEDRIVER_URL" \
    && unzip -o /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /tmp \
    && rm -rf /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip \
    && mv -f /tmp/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver" \
    && chmod +x "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
```

According to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection as of version 115 Google has changed the release process for Chrome and Chromedriver. There are multiple [JSON endpoints](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing#json-api-endpoints) that you can probe for latest stable version of both Chrome and Chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Manager is now fully included with `selenium` `4.10.0`, so this is all you need (for Python):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.

You can also find a specific driver for a particular milestone with this endpoint: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/latest-versions-per-milestone-with-downloads.json

---

If you're wondering why you're now seeing this error for `ChromeDriverManager`, it's because https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114 due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

Comment: Can you please clarify where this download will be saved on the system?

Comment: Selenium saves drivers to `~/.cache/selenium/`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome - Downloads](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0) page you will find the last version of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) to be published was [ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.90/).

So if you are using Chrome version 115 or newer you have to check the [Chrome for Testing availability](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) dashboard which provides convenient [JSON endpoints](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing#json-api-endpoints) for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.

---

### [**Selenium Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447)

With the availability of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above you don't need to explicitly download [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) or any browser drivers as such using [*webdriver_manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447). You just need to ensure that the desired browser client i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) is installed.

[Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) is the new tool integrated with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) that would help to get a working webdriver version to run Selenium out of the box. Beta 1 of [Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76555236/7429447) will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the *`PATH`*.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can simply do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

### tl; dr

[Chrome for Testing: reliable downloads for browser automation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

I am finding the same on macOS.

*selenium-webdriver 4.10.0*, which never changed.

My Chrome is up-to-date and is in the same path.  So this seems to be with a recent version of Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really easy for this one. Use Selenium 4.9.0. stable version.

In this version, there isn't any need to download the *chromedriver.exe* file. In this version, Selenium Manager handles the drivers, and it is now working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if Selenium Manager finds your browser and the driver correctly with:

```
$ ./VS/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.4.11.0/manager/windows/selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome
INFO    Driver path: C:\%USER%\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\115.0.5790.170\chromedriver.exe
INFO    Browser path: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

This is the output from my development environment, but on the runners this didn't work and the automatic download failed, because those URLs are blocked on my companies network:

- https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

For chrome, if you are using [Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/) then you just need to add this packages drivers to your `PATH` and the above command should find the driver. Additionally, you need to install the correct browser version compatible with the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the link for win32 instead of win64.
win32 contains the Chromedriver and will solve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The links for both Chrome and chromedriver versions can be found [here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json) (in a JSON friendly format, not user friendly). You'll need to expand the nodes to search for the specific version

Answer (score -1):

If you use the **4.10.0** **Selenium** version then this issue will not come. But for the chrome binary issue, [this link will help](https://qatestauto.com/chromedriver-115-stopped-working-on-mac-and-windows/):

> ### Issue
>
> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
> ```
>
> Currently, there was some change announced by
> Chromedriver. Here are the complete details. After that, So many
> issues are coming.
>
> ### Solution
>
> Below is the quick fix for Mac users (Who are using Selenium 4.10.0)
>
> ```
> ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
> options.setBinary("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
> WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
> ```
>
> In Mac, machine error is due to the binary.
> After specifying the binary path this will work!!