# No such driver version 115.0.5790.110 for linux64 error using ChromeDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I have a python script where it autoinstalls chromedriver with `ChromeDriverManager` package. Today it gave me an error of:

```
No such driver version 115.0.5790.110 for linux64
```

Line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
```

ChromeDriverManagergoes to the [url](https://%60https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/%60)  and istalls `LATEST RELEASE` of chrome driver. I looked at last modified version, it says on may of 2023. But [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746946/unable-to-download-chrome-driver-for-version-115) says it is having an issue newly. My script also was working a week ago.

```
<Contents>
<Key>LATEST_RELEASE</Key>
<Generation>1685523462105569</Generation>
<MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
<LastModified>2023-05-31T08:57:42.224Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"368684b889419678b04e4899d53d7ab0"</ETag>
<Size>13</Size>
</Contents>
```

I looked at some [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746946/unable-to-download-chrome-driver-for-version-115),  as I guess it is related new version of chromedriver release which does not function well?

Could anyone assure me that, I got it right, and that means I need to change script to take the old version of chromedriver from path?

Comment: i had a very similar error.  after a long time of using it, this happened (on windows). So i moved to playwright: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsc4js6DM6g&ab_channel=DarrenLefcoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer you have to check the [Chrome for Testing availability](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) dashboard which provides convenient [JSON endpoints](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing#json-api-endpoints) for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.

---

### [Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447)

With the availability of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above you don't need to explicitly download [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) or any browser drivers as such using [*webdriver_manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447). You just need to ensure that the desired browser client i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) is installed.

[Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) is the new tool integrated with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) that would help to get a working environment to run Selenium out of the box. Beta 1 of [*Selenium Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76555236/7429447) will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the *`PATH`*.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can simply do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

### tl; dr

[Chrome for Testing: reliable downloads for browser automation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/)

Comment: I guess, there is need someone to write an article or make youtube videos for how to use these `API endpoints`, or what is the reason  to install `npx puppeter chromium `which version (stable, canary)...before i was downloading chromium, and `chrome.exe` putting their path in the script. Now, there are so many details..

Comment: @miPythOff I had been explaining this since Selenium v4.6.0 landed. Unfortunately I'm not a YouTuber :)