# Is Selenium WebDriver version: 4.10.0 compatible with ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 and Chrome browser Version 115.0.5790.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am trying to learn automation with Selenium but I got stuck with WebDriver... I followed all the steps. Installed the following, configured PATH:

Chromedriver version : ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63
Selenium WebDriver version: 4.10.0

Eclipse IDE version:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
Build id: 20230608-1333

java 20.0.1 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)

---

But when I try to do small project like invoking Chrome Browser... I am getting this error...
WebDriver Can not be resolved to a type.
ChromeDriver can not be resolved to a type;

I don't see the option to 'import ....'.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve the error.

Thank you.

Tried all the tips suggested from Youtube videos but no luck

Comment: Finally I was able to invoke chrome browser ... the solution I tried is created a folder called drivers under the project and pasted the chromedriver.exe file... Now I see the import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;                                                                      So I am able to launch the browser, open a website, close the browser etc...                                Thanks to everyone for their inputs... I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium version `4.10.0`, then you do not have to worry about the browser version or the `chromedriver` version. Selenium will internally download/manage the `chromedriver` based on the installed chrome browser on your system. Java code to launch a browser can be as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();
}
```

Imports required:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Thank you Shawn. But my problem is I don't see the import option ... gives error but no option to import...

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) version doesn't have any ***documented*** dependency on [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) version or [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version as such.

But matching the ***major version*** of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version is mandatory.

However, ideally you should be using the latest version of all the binaries:

- *Selenium*
- *ChromeDriver*
- *Google Chrome*

---

Using the latest *Selenium v4.10.0* and  *Chrome v115.x* [Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795080/7429447) download the matching *ChromeDriver* as per the version of *Google Chrome* installed. Your minimal code will be:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://weather.com/");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50697221/7429447)
- [Server terminated early with status 1 error with Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser and the log message "Only local connections are allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551748/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the latest version of selenium java 4.11.0--https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/
Its working for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rishi... I will try to download the latest version of Selenium Java 4.11.0.