# Chromedriver version 116 bug

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Has anyone succeeded in fixing the bug with the new release? My current Chrome browser version is 116.0.5845.111 and I downloaded the Chrome driver version 116 from [this](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) source as they instructed and I'm sure the path to the Chrome driver is correct but I'm still getting this error:

> This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
> Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111

People are talking about it in [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/230521170/requires-version-116-of-the-google-chrome-driver%EF%BC%8Cplease?hl=en) thread.

Please advise if you have a working solution.

Comment: I managed to solve it and it was indeed solved by downloading the correct chromedriver depending on whether you're using Linux, Windows, etc. and by setting correctly the executable_path option. Unfortunately you don't provide details regarding your code or the operating system you're using

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76937742/3782128

Answer (score 0):

For `undetected-chromedriver`, there's a solution in this thread: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1477#issuecomment-1680867979

---

Until a direct fix is available (meaning that `undetected-chromedriver` starts using the updated driver locations), you can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode as an alternative, which has a slightly modified version of `undetected-chromedriver`.

First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

---

##### SeleniumBase also has other formats with its own API:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    sb.sleep(3)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1"):
        sb.get_new_driver(undetectable=True)
        sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
        sb.sleep(3)
    sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1", timeout=3)
```