# No stable Selenium Chrome Webdriver for the latest Google Chrome version according to the availability matrix

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, version

I am trying to use Selenium for Chrome web browser automation using Python 3.11.4.  My Google Chrome version is "115.0.5790.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)".  I go to https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/ to download chromedriver.  This links to the availability matrix: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/.

[Screenshot of the availability matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xoGe.jpg)

The availability matrix appears to say there is no stable Chrome webdriver for version 115.0.5790.110.  Is this assumption correct?

I tried downloading webdriver from "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.110/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip", but the link doesn't work.

I also tried installing an older Chrome (Chromium) version, but that seemed cause other problems - since it is not actually Chrome, I wasn't sure how to point the webdriver to it.

From reading a similar post, it looks like running an older Chrome version and setting it to not update is the solution.  If so, is there a guide for this?  How do I deal with differences between Chrome and Chromium, and the fact that Chromium doesn't seem to actually get installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer you have to check the [Chrome for Testing availability](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) dashboard which provides convenient [JSON endpoints](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing#json-api-endpoints) for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.

---

### Selenium Manager

With the availability of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above you don't need to explicitly download [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) or any browser drivers as such. You just need to ensure that the desired browser client i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) is installed.

[Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) is the new tool integrated with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) that would help to get a working webdriver version to run Selenium out of the box. Beta 1 of [Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76555236/7429447) will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the *`PATH`*.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can simply do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears v115 is handled differently (doesn't auto download the new chrome for testing broswer but 116, 117 and on do.

This is discussed (for Java) at:
https://youtu.be/NSmEaOEeusE?si=wv1bxRGUAMQWDok-&t=622