# Can not run .EXE have selenium in other computer don't install selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I convert code to file exe by pyinstaller . I can run this file in my computer, but when I sent this file to someone, they can't run it and have error message . Please give me solution for this issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrcfD.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver 

link = "ABC.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1800,750)
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='200%'")
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(22)
array = ['panel1','panel2','panel3','panel4','panel5','panel6']
for i in array:
    element = driver.find_element('id', i)
    element.screenshot(f'c:\\daten\\{i}.jpg')
driver.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553813/messageunable-to-obtain-chromedriver-using-selenium-manager