# Selenium - chromedriver and google-chrome: error on same versions

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have `google-chrome` and `chromedriver` installed on EC2, and they both have the same version.

```
$ google-chrome-stable -version
Google Chrome 109.0.5414.74 
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172})
```

But once I run a Selenium script, it fails with the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:47871
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 110
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.74
```

How is it possible since I have a single version of `chromedriver` which is installed in `/usr/bin`?

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
uc.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Did you try specifying the chromediver-path explicitly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858817/20443541)

Comment: yes, I did:
`import undetected_chromedriver as uc`


`uc.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')`

Answer (score 0):

From the console though it seems you are using *ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74*:

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172})
```

But somewhere in your program or within the framework settings [ChromeDriver v110.0.5481.77](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=110.0.5481.77/) is/gets downloaded and is being used to initiate the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) / [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

As per the *Release Notes* of [ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (2023-02-08)](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/110.0.5481.77/notes.txt):

```
Supports Chrome version 110
```

Where as you are still using ***Version 109.0.5414.120***. Hence the mismatch and the error.

Comment: Interesting, but how to identify the source of the problem since I explicitly specify the chromdriver path?

Comment: @Mike Can't comment further without the visibility to the framework you are using.