# Selenium + webdriver_manager results in WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

**Solution: Selenium's new tool known as SeleniumManager will do what ChromeDriverManager used to do.  No need to use webdriver_manager **

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Run Chrome without the sandbox
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode (no GUI)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

---

I'm trying to run the code below, but getting the following error:

> WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /Users/abc/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/115.0.5790.114/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Run Chrome without the sandbox
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode (no GUI)
options.binary_location="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = options)
```

I've done the following:

1. Ensuring ChromeDriver binary has executable permission for the non-root user.
2. Ensure that /etc/hosts file contains `127.0.0.1 localhost`
3. ChromeDriver executable file is the correct version for the installed version of Chrome (see image below)
4. Verify that the path to the ChromeDriver executable is correct: `/Users/abc/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/115.0.5790.114/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver`
5. I've added `/Users/abc/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/` as a path environment variable.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Check these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/76728148/7598774

Comment: @Shawn that worked, feel free to post as answer and I'll approve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause of this issue:** Chromium team have done some modifications to their drivers, the last stable driver version is `v114`. If your system is on browser version `v115`, then `WebDriverManager` is not finding and downloading the `v115` driver from Chromium website. This is the cause of the issue.

[image]

Reference Link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**SOLUTION:** You can try one of the below:

**Option 1**. Force `WDM` to use driver `v114`, see code below

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.90").install()),options=options)
```

**Option 2**. If you are using Selenium `v4.6.0` or higher, you can just get rid of `WebDriverManager`, as Selenium's new tool `SeleniumManager` does what `WDM` used to do. So `WDM` is not needed anymore to handle browser drivers. Refer the answer below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76728148/7598774

### UPDATE:

 YOU CAN USE THE **"NEW CHROME FOR TESTING"** BROWSER AND `v115` CHROMEDRIVER FROM FOLLOWING LINK [CHROME FOR TESTING](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)

**Option 3.**: Use below code to launch new "Chrome For Testing" browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service('C:\User\drivers\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe') # v115 chromedriver.exe path
options = Options()
options.binary_location= 'C:\\User\\browsers\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe' # v115 new ChromeFortesting browser path
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

**Result:**
[image]

**New "Chrome For testing" browser logo is slightly different(See below):**
Left side is regular Chrome browser and right side is new Chrome For Testing browser.

[image]

Comment: Still had some persisting issues after applying the solutions provided here, what fixed it was running the following: ```brew install chromedriver```.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium just added support for chromedriver 115 in the latest versions (`4.11.2`):

[image]

(Technically `4.11.0`, but due to a bug, get `4.11.2` or newer for Python.)

---

If you're wondering why you're now seeing this error for `ChromeDriverManager`, it's because https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114 due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

---

Selenium Manager is now fully included with `selenium` `4.11.2`, so you no longer need to use `webdriver-manager`/`ChromeDriverManager`. This is all you need now:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Add additional options as needed, such as:

```py
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.