# Selenium Driver issue - Unable to run the script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, selenium-edgedriver, edgedriver

I'm unable to run the selenium script after providing the driver path.
The installed edge browser version -
Microsoft Edge
Version 115.0.1901.188 (Official build) (64-bit)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h4lL.png)
Driver installed into my Windows 10 64 bit laptop-
Product Version - 115.0.1901.188
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfrqJ.png)

Please let me know why I'm seeing getting below exception when running the script.
PFA, below for more details
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RBIP.png)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Shreyansh Singh

When running my selenium code using Java in Eclipse.
Downloaded the edge browser and it's present under mentioned path in script.

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76799299/7598774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Selenium `v4.10.0`, you don't really need to set the driver executable path anymore. If you do not provide the driver path, selenium's new tool `SeleniumManager` will download/handle the drivers for you.

So remove the `System.setProperty` line from your code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");        
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently due to the latest update of Chrome browser the below script is getting failed.
FYI, I'm using selenium version 4
Error Message-

Failure reason-
Aug 23, 2023 10:16:27 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Host info: host: 'RAGHUVANSHISHRE', ip: '192.168.217.1'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.16'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}]}]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:154)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:107)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:87)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:50)
at NaveenAutomationLabs.checkBoxSelection.main(checkBoxSelection.java:13)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVEKM.png)

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).