# ValueError: There is no such driver by url Version 115.0.5790.110

Tags: selenium-webdriver, service, valueerror, ng-options, webdriver-manager

Hi I am using Selenium on Windows 10, since 2 days I keep getting the following error initially I did not have this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Maybe due to an update Google Chrome Version `115.0.5790.110`

I tried one of Stackoverflow's suggested solutions, but it didn't work

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Chrome Version 115.0.5790.110

Answer (score 0):

Chromium team have made some recent changes to `chromedriver`. The last stable version is `v114`. From `v115` they are going to release 2 different browsers, one for regular browsing and one dedicated for automation testing.

**Source:**

- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

**Solution:** For now you try one of the follwoing:

1. Force `ChromeDriverManager` to use `v114` as below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.90").install()),options=options)
```

2. Looks like you are using old version of Selenium. Just upgrade selenium to your latest version. If your selenium version is `v4.6.0` or above, you don't need to set driver path nor you need third party library like `WebDriverManager` to handle browser drivers. Selenium's new tool `SeleniumManager` will internally handle browser drivers, code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

**Source:** [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

**Useful links** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76799299/7598774