# Selenium and Python Issue for PATH

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, error-handling

Here is my code I tried different path versions but I am not able to run this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Specify the path to the Chrome WebDriver executable
PATH = "C:\Users\CHEEMN2\Downloads\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64/to/chromedriver.exe"  # Replace with the actual path on your system

# Create a Chrome WebDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)

# Open a URL
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

# Close the WebDriver when done
driver.quit()
```

This is the error i keep on getting

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\CHEEMN2\OneDrive - CPGGPC\Python\import os.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CHEEMN2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CHEEMN2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 71, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\CHEEMN2\OneDrive - CPGGPC\Python\import os.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CHEEMN2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\CHEEMN2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CHEEMN2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.683 seconds
```

I am using VS code for web scraping.

I have tried to to check all the versions for
Python 3.11.4

I downloaded this version for Chrome
chrome version 116.0.5845.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Bypass)
chromedriver    win64   https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

the selenium version is
python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.**version**)"
4.11.2

Answer (score 1):

Let the built-in driver manager of selenium `4.11.2` do all the work for you. You don't need to specify a path anymore (and you can't pass it directly into the `Chrome()` call ... use the `Service()` arg instead.)

Here's code that launches Chrome, while giving you the ability to change options via `ChromeOptions()` and `Service()`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ... Anything you want to automate ...
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using selenium `v4.11.2`, you do not have to manually provide the path of driver. Selenium can download and manage it for you.

Your code can be simplified to:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Create a Chrome WebDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open a URL
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

# Close the WebDriver when done
driver.quit()
```

For more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76728148/7598774
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Comment: Selenium 4.16.0 which is installed by `pip install --upgrade selenium` results in : 
An Exception found : Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location