# Upgrading Selenium to version 4.11

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have Selenium (Python) version 4.7.2 .
I updated Chrome to version 116 and since then Selenium doesn't work.
I realized that I need to upgrade the Selenium version to version 4.11 .
How do I update a version easily?
And yes, I would love to know what disadvantages (if any) this version has.

This is the code I have:

```
e_driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

I tried adding manually, but it didn't work.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(version='116.0').install()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest selenium version `v4.12.0` is what you need ideally as this version includes support for chrome version `116`, see below:

[image]

Ever since selenium `v4.6.0` is released, selenium has an in-built driver management tool known as [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/). This means you do not need a third party library such as `ChromeDriverManager` for your driver management. Your code can be now as simple as below:

```
e_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76728148/7598774

**UPDATE:** How to upgrade selenium version in PyCharm!

- Press <kbd>Ctrl + alt + s</kbd>  --> Navigate to <kbd>Python Interpreter</kbd> --> Search selenium and upgrade to the latest version as shown below

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I update to version 4.12?

Comment: What IDE do you use? PyCharm?

Comment: Yes. I use PyCharm