# Using Selenium on Mac Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

Recently got a mac and was able to run Mozilla without any issues but having trouble installing chrome extensions and running it for selenium. Can someone guide me through the process of installing the extension and running selenium on Mac chrome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that the easy way for running mac osx, chrome and selenium together is like this on mac os terminal:

```
# download selenium jar
curl -L0 https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.9/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -o selenium-server-standalone.jar

# install chromedriver using cask
brew cask install chromedriver

# start chrome driver
brew services start chromedriver                                                                                                                                                                      
#==> Successfully started `chromedriver` (label:homebrew.mxcl.chromedriver)

# start selenium server
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar                                                                                                                                                                           
#14:38:20.684 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50'
#14:38:20.685 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
```

Comment: When running 'brew services start chromedriver', I get 'No available formula with the name "chromedriver"', any idea why?

Comment: Maybe now has a new name, or formula, check with this brew services list, it should be installed

Comment: Nope, even after running `brew cask install chromedriver` theres nothing under `brew services list`

Answer (score 41):

If you want to use Selenium WebDriver with Chrome, first download ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome. This can be installed via Homebrew with `brew install chromedriver`, or manually by downloading, extracting, moving and setting the `PATH` as follows:

```
$ cd $HOME/Downloads
$ wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.22/chromedriver_mac32.zip
$ unzip chromedriver_mac32.zip
$ mkdir -p $HOME/bin
$ mv chromedriver $HOME/bin
$ echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
```

**Source:** [install and set path to chromedriver on mac or linux](http://codrspace.com/rails4sandeep/install-and-set-path-to-chromedriver-on-mac-or-linux/)

You should then read [Getting started with ChromeDriver on Desktop](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/), in particular the sample code which shows how you map the path to the executable and  instantiate `ChromeDriver`. If you have a reference to the driver in the `PATH` variable, you can omit the configuration line.

You can install both packed (.crx file) and unpacked (directory) extensions via ChromeDriver. See the code snippets for setting either up [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions).

If you were using Selenium IDE for FireFox instead, there is no version available for Chrome. The best alternative I know of is [iMacros for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp).

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you please guide me through the process of installing brew install chromedriver. I tried to install it from terminal but cant seem to do it. I have also searched for a solution online but dint work out.

Comment: @Ravi You need to install the [Homebew](http://brew.sh/) package manager. You just need to run the command they put the website, which downloads the installation source and executes it via the ruby interpreter

Comment: I have done using "brew tap homebrew/cask" and "brew cask install chromedriver" on Terminal (MacOS)

Answer (score 29):

Sometimes you will face a problem with the old version of `chromedriver` and when you try to install it using this command:

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

It shows you the following:

```
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'; not linking.
```

However, you can the following step:

```
brew cask reinstall chromedriver
```

If it still shows you the same error, you can remove it with the following command

```
rm /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

and install it again

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

You should have the last updated version of chrome driver

Comment: Thanks buddy. Didn't hit me the idea of just removing the driver and install.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you have a couple of options.

- either manually downloading chrome driver and adding it to your `PATH`,
- or using `webdriver_manager` package

---

**Manually downloading chromedriver**

The first option is to manually download chromedriver and add it your `PATH`:

***Step 1: Download `chromedriver`***

```
# You can find more recent/old versions at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/81.0.4044.69/chromedriver_mac64.zip
```

***Step 2: Add chromedriver to your `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`)***

```
unzip chromedriver_mac64.zip
cp chromedriver /usr/local/bin
```

You should now be able to run

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
```

without any issues

---

**Using `webdriver_manager`**

Alternatively, you can use `webdriver_manager` that contains most web drivers.

First install it with `pip`:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

And for Chrome in particular, you should do

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
```

Answer (score 6):

1. One way is if you have homebrew on your mac, then on terminal, use this command
   `brew install chromedriver`
2. Then you need to download chromedriver on your machine, do it from
   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
   Download latest version
   It will look like, "chromedriver_mac32.zip"
   (doesn't matter if its 32 bit, it will work for 64 bit MAC as well)
3. Use this code for open Chrome if your chromedriver that you downloaded is inside your project folder and looks like this
   ..Project folder/Chrome/chromedriver

   ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Chrome/chromedriver");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip to just list out the actual full path to chromedriver!

Answer (score 3):

Use chrome driver, download from here
https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Add the file in pycharm project, then use this cmd to disable permission pop up

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine chromedriver
```

Also in python program, use these lines, make sure chrome is installed in Applications

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/<Username>/PycharmProjects/selenium_py/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

Install chromedriver directly with `brew install chromedriver`.
The chrome driver is located in `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`.
If you reload your terminal with `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`, depending on your setup or restart the terminal if should work.
If it does not work add the chrome driver to your PATH. You need to add `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc by adding the line:  `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this after downloading the right chromedriver is with the oneliner:
`sudo chmod a+x chromedriver && sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`