# Python + Splinter: Error - httplib.BadStatusLine: ''

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, browser, splinter

In my python project, I'm using Splinter (https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to open a browser and attempt visit a site:

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser('chrome')
browser.visit('http://www.google.com')
```

And the browser opened up, and without being able to visit `http://www.google.com`, it got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 90, in <module>
    browser = Browser('chrome')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/chrome.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 185, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 247, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 488, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1132, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Weirdly, it works on a different Mac computer, but when I transferred it to another Mac computer, encountered that error.

Researched around but could not make out what the real problem is. What could I be doing wrong? And how should I go about resolving the issue?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer

Comment: Have you verified the chromedriver version on the Mac computer where it failing?

Comment: @gipsy How can I do so? And what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you are describing point to the *outdated chromedriver*. Go to the ["ChromeDriver Downloads"](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page and download the latest driver. For the currently latest stable Chrome 58, you need `chromedriver` 2.29.

Note that to check the `chromedriver` version, execute:

```
$ chromedriver --version
```

And, also, make sure you have the latest `splinter` and `selenium`:

```
$ pip install -U splinter selenium
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. Is there a way to install the latest `chromedriver` via terminal? Because if I do it manually, there seem to be an issue with setting up the path.

Comment: @JoKo have not tried that, but it looks like there is [this option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38087347/771848). Thanks.

Comment: still having trouble. I checked the chromedriver version and it was 2.22. Tried installing and it keeps saying I have chromedriver 2.22, and updated both splinter/selenium as suggested yet still getting the same error...