# Css selector issue with rvest and NHL statistics

Tags: html, css, r, rvest

I want to scrape data from hockey-reference.com, specifically from this link:

https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_1991.html

I want the 4th table, called "Team Statistics," and I also want to subtract the first and last rows (but that can be for another time).

Initially, I want to get the scrape working with the 1991 link, but I want to eventually scrape every link from 1991 to 2017.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

stat_urls <- "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_1991.html"
```

Right now, I have the 1991 link only, for simplicity. I cannot seem to find the correct css selection, even though I have tried multiple different ones, after a pretty thorough search using the "inspect" source of the actual webpage. I have tried the following css selections:

```
table#stats.sortable.stats_table.now.sortable
#stats
#all_stats
#all_stats > div.table_outer_container
#stats
#stats > tbody
#div_stats (and all sorts of combos with this one)
```

None of these work, when used in the following code:

```
team_stats <- stat_urls %>% 
 read_html() %>%
 html_nodes("#stats") %>% 
 html_table(header = T)
```

All attempts with "xpath=" also failed. Any help with this would be absolutely phenomenal, and Go Preds!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using RSelenium. Saw a similar answer here: [Web Scraping Basketball Reference using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778493/web-scraping-basketball-reference-using-r).

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
startServer() 
remDr<-remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_1991.html")
page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
table <- html_table(page, fill = TRUE)
table[[28]]
```

It's a pain to install selenium though and I would try to help with that too but I installed it a while ago so don't really remember. Good luck

---

From the guy who posted the original question:

The above answer worked, but I had to go through Homebrew:

```
https://brew.sh/
```

And then I had to use the following code from here:

[Using Selenium on Mac Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081021/using-selenium-on-mac-chrome?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
# download selenium jar
curl -L0 https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.9/selenium- 
server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -o selenium-server-standalone.jar

# install chromedriver
brew install chromedriver

# start chrome driver
brew services start chromedriver                                                                                                                                                                      
#==> Successfully started `chromedriver` 
(label:homebrew.mxcl.chromedriver)

# start selenium server
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar                                                                                                                                                                           
#14:38:20.684 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: 
'63f7b50'
#14:38:20.685 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 
4444
```

Comment: I downloaded RSelenium with no problem using devtools, but I can't get connected to wherever it is supposed to connect to...will keep working on it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the startServer() is now defunct...so I think I am supposed to use rsDriver()... confused on how to connect that. Hmm

Comment: You can call `rsDriver(geckover = NULL,  phantomver = NULL)` to load the RSelenium driver to use with Chrome.  (The two args turn off support for Gecko, i.e. Firefox, and PhantomJS, a browser simulator.  You might want `verbose = FALSE` once things are working.)

Comment: @user2554330 - the code comes back "could not determine server status" - any thoughts? Something to do with "port" ?

Comment: If the port was an issue, you'd get a different error.  This looks like it might be a Java problem, or something else stopping the Selenium server from starting.  I don't know how to fix it, other than suggesting a Java update and re-install of Selenium.  (Unfortunately, the re-install is hard:  RSelenium will have tried to install it somewhere, and you'll need to find that location and delete the files.)

Comment: @user2554330 Is there a way to loop for 27 different links, without opening 27 different browser windows? My computer will explode lol

Comment: Sure, use the same `remDr` for all of them, just navigate to them one at a time.