# RSelenium Installation on MacBook, with Chrome

Tags: r, macos, selenium, rselenium

I have RSelenium (the package) installed, to do some scraping of NHL statistics from hockeyreference.com

It was working, all fine, but recently stopped working, giving this error:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to 
localhost port 4567: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.

$client
[1] "No sessionInfo. Client browser is mostly likely not opened."

$server
Process Handle
command : /private/var/folders/dk/kf4tf83n1lg40687w6fmq5wh0000gn/T/Rtmpiy1cOY/file1d1856ef53ae.sh 
system id : 18786
state     : exited
Warning message:
In rsDriver(port = 4567L, geckover = NULL, phantomver = NULL) :
   Could not determine server status.
```

I've tried reinstalling, but could not get it working. My original install is outlined in this question (using homebrew, with the latest chromedriver installed):

[Css selector issue with rvest and NHL statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193152/css-selector-issue-with-rvest-and-nhl-statistics)

Any help would be great. The code I'm running with RSelenium is here:

https://github.com/papelr/nhldatar/blob/master/nhldatar/R/nhldatar-phase-2.R

TL;DR, I can't get the rsDriver argument to work, and it gives the error posted above:

```
rsDriver(port = 4567L, geckover = NULL, phantomver = NULL)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```

If RSelenium works (opening a chrome browser), then the rest of this will run! Thanks!

Comment: author of the package recommends to run RSelenium via docker: https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: I think that is only for Windows/Linux @Mislav

Comment: I don't see a reason why can't you do it on mac. I have just found this link for example: https://www.raynergobran.com/2017/01/rselenium-mac-update/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reccomend to:

- install docker for Mac,
- pull the image for chrome, firefox (recommend version 3.5.1) or phantom
- run image in docker: docker run...
- create remotedriver:

  remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "here you IP", port = 4445L,
                          browserName = "firefox")
- if you have debug version you can watch in VNC what are you doing