# Which is the path to launch chromium from selenium in linux?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use selenium for web scraping, but I'm not able to load a site on the browser, this is my initial code:

```
import time
import os,sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
driver_1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver_1.get(url)
```

With that code at get an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Which corresponds to this line:

```
driver_1 = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Hence I tried the `whereis chromium-browser` command and got this paths:

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser 
/etc/chromium-browser 
/usr/lib/chromium-browser 
/usr/bin/X11/chromium-browser 
/usr/share/chromium-browser 
/usr/share/man/man1/chromium-browser.1.gz
```

But for each of them I get errors, for this one:

```
driver_1 = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromium-browser")
```

I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromium-browser unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

I'm using python 2.7X

EDIT:

I have found the answer at the correct path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476112/using-chromedriver-with-selenium-python-ubuntu):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
```

For that to work it is required to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Comment: have you tried some of the solutions listed in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co

Comment: @wpercy Error code it's different, I think he pathsI'm using are wrong but I dont know the correct one.

Comment: yeah, I know the error code is different, but exit code `0` typically means that it exited without any errors. I think it's worth looking at.

Comment: @wpercy I found the answer, now I'm getting other version related errors.