# Scroll down google reviews with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the reviews from this link:

https://www.google.com/search?q=google+reviews+2nd+chance+treatment+40th+street&rlz=1C1JZAP_enUS697US697&oq=google+reviews+2nd+chance+treatment+40th+street&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6183j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x872b7179b68e33d5:0x24b5517d86a95f89,1

For what I'm using the following code to load the page

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import time
import argparse
import os
import time

#Define the argument parser to read in the URL

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+reviews+2nd+chance+treatment+40th+street&rlz=1C1JZAP_enUS697US697&oq=google+reviews+2nd+chance+treatment+40th+street&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6183j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x872b7179b68e33d5:0x24b5517d86a95f89,1"


# Initialize the Chrome webdriver and open the URL
#driver = webdriver.Chromium()


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476112/using-chromedriver-with-selenium-python-ubuntu
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(2)



SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

The page load fine, it is not scrolling down, I have used the same code for other sites like linkedn and it works there.

Comment: Are you scrolling down to load any elements on the page?

Comment: Yes, I need to scroll to get all the reviews.

Comment: check my answer below and let me know how it goes. Not sure when you say `all` that's why I gave the option of `desiredReviewsCount` in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic that you can use without using the javascript scroll down. Simple and effective by using the `location_once_scrolled_into_view` method which will scroll to the element.

As part of logic below, we are scrolling to the last review, and then checking if we loaded the number of reviews desired as per the request.

**Imports Needed:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

change the `desiredReviewsCount` variable value as per your requirement in the below code.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+reviews+2nd+chance+treatment+40th+street&rlz=1C1JZAP_enUS697US697&oq=google+reviews+2nd+chance+treatment+40th+street&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6183j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x872b7179b68e33d5:0x24b5517d86a95f89,1"
driver.get(url)
x=0
desiredReviewsCount=30
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block']//div[@class='WMbnJf gws-localreviews__google-review']")))
while x<desiredReviewsCount:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block']//div[@class='WMbnJf gws-localreviews__google-review'])[last()]").location_once_scrolled_into_view
    x = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block']//div[@class='WMbnJf gws-localreviews__google-review']"))

print (len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block']//div[@class='WMbnJf gws-localreviews__google-review']")))
```

[image]

Comment: Is not working for me, it seems it moves the side bar to the end of the initial page but it does not force to load the reviews below.

Comment: which version of FF and selenium you are using. I don't see any issue (Attached the gif). Sorry for the low quality gif, I could not upload high quality screenshot due to screenshot size limit.

Comment: I'm using selenium-3.141 and chromium 73 on linux mint. Which version are you using?

Comment: Ahhha... Seems to be the issue is with chrome browser (able to reproduce your issue in chrome) FF doesn't had this issue. Can you switch to FF or do you want me to dig more into this issue?

Comment: That's fine, I can switch to FF. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! But still trying to understand the reason why it's not triggering the scroll event  chrome.