# Install chromedriver on Mac M1 at specific location?

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I just made the jump from Ubuntu to MacBook Air M1.

I am trying to set-up the system in a way that I don't have to change scripts for both. i.e. I want to keep the scripts in such a way that editing on either system is ok.

In a script I use the following line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
```

I used Homebrew to install `chromium-browser` but I can't find the file (so I can move it to this location?).

I have tried almost everything I could look up and can't figure it out. What can I try next?

Answer (score 9):

The fastest way to to solve is using Home Brew:

```
brew install --cask chromedriver
```

Chromedriver will be installed in the correct path.

Comment: FWIW after install via `brew` I still needed to mark the application as "safe" in macOS, I followed the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362134/1371489

Answer (score 7):

Install webdriver-manager, it allows you install and store chromedrive automatically

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

and use like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to keep the scripts unchanged between the two machines. I want to be able to edit the scripts on both machines without changing the path.

Comment: @Sid with that library you just use like that and driver is downloaded automatically

Comment: is not usefull when  headless

Comment: @marti_ is it a question?doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I got blank page when I added this option to drive
options.add_argument("--headless")

Comment: @marti_ it's weardo, it shouldn't open the page at all when --headless in argument options

Answer (score 1):

You can find the downloads for various versions of the Chrome driver here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

For example, for v99 on Mac M1 you could download this archive: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip

Once downloaded just unzip & copy to whatever location you choose. After I installed I still needed to mark the application as "safe" in macOS, I followed the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362134/1371489