# SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97 Current browser version is 100.0.4896.75

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm trying to start a selenium webdriverinstance, but I get this error:

```
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97 Current browser version is 100.0.4896.75 with binary path *path here*
```

I already tried using chromium 98, it works, but a new vulnerability was found in version 100 and i would like to update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message...

```
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97 Current browser version is 100.0.4896.75 with binary path...
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=100.0.4896.75*
- You are using *chromedriver=97.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=97.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 97

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=97.0* and the *chrome=100.0.4896.75*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to [ChromeDriver v100.0.4896.60](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/) level which matches to ***chrome=100.0.4896.75***.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. As a sidenote, `Selenium Webdriver` truly is a nightmare to install and maintain. The fact that chromedriver only works with one version at a time and must constantly be kept in sync w/ Chrome's auto updates are just one of the reasons why this tech is 'advanced' as far as how difficult it is to maintain. On our team only one person's e2e tests run properly, due to webdriver install/versioning/dependency/OS/CPU issues (yes, all of those). As an Angular dev I'm glad Protractor is being deprecated and can't wait to jump to something like Cypress (does not use Webdriver).

Answer (score 11):

On a mac M1, I was getting the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError:
        session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 103
        Current browser version is 105.0.5195.125 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
          (Driver info: chromedriver=103.0.5060.134 (8ec6fce403b3feb0869b0732eda8bd95011d333c-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#1262}),platform=Mac OS X 12.5.1 arm64)
```

I simply upgraded the chromedriver using `brew` and it fixed the issue for me.

`brew upgrade chromeDriver`

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to manually kill a still-running chromedriver process before the upgrade took effect.

Comment: This worked for me. On macOS sonoma, I also saw `“chromedriver” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.` so I ran `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine $(which chromedriver)` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019725/5783745))

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps others, **yum install chromium** installed Chromium version 102 while **npm install -g chromedriver** installs version 103, which requires chromium version 103.

I'm sure rolling back to older versions is not the *best* solution, but for me, installing the complementary version of chromedriver got things running on my system. To install the older version of chromedriver that would align with the chromium version installed by yum, I first went here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and copied the version number for 102 (in this case 102.0.5005.61)

Then, installing the "*correct*" version of chromedriver was accomplished by running
`CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=102.0.5005.61 npm install -g chromedriver`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if both Chrome browser version and ChromeDriver versions are in sync, then maybe you should look for the directory from where you project is invoking it, means there could some other directory from where ChromeDriver is being executed and whose version is incompatible with the browser.

In my case, my VS Code was picking up ChromeDriver from project's directory node_modules/.bin/ChromeDriver, so i replaced this with the latest and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users, I ran into the same problem. My Chrome got auto updated to version 118 (main). And Selenium was reporting

```
  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError:
    session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 116
    Current browser version is 118.0.5993.70 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

I had to brew update my system with the following command and it was all fine.

```
 brew -v update; brew upgrade --force-bottle; brew upgrade --cask; brew doctor; brew cleanup
```

This command updated the Chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that i updated the chromedriver to the newest chrome version via:

`npm run e2e:update-webdriver` which executes: `webdriver-manager update --gecko false`

Therefore, the chromedriver version was higher than the chrome browser version. To fix this discrepancy I had to run:

`sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem. Usually, I'd fix this by changing the version number in my `package.json` file to match my chrome browser version. This worked until chromedriver v115 came out. For chromedriver v115, it still worked even though the browser version didn't match. That is I could put in my `package.json`:

```json
 "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=114.0.5735.248",
```

While my browser was 115.0.5790.170. The end to end tests still worked.

Now that chromedriver v116 came out and my browser updated to v116.0.5845.96, the above doesn't work anymore. My workaround was to download the *chromedriver-win64.zip* and put it in *C:\your project\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium* and extract it. Then you'll have a *chromedriver-win64* folder with the *chromedrive.exe* file. Next is update the `update-config.json` file to make it point to the latest chromedriver. Update the last like so:

```json
{
  "gecko": {
    ...
  },
  "chrome": {
    "last": "C:\\your project\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe",
    "all": [
      "C:\\your project\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_83.0.4103.39.exe",
      "C:\\your project\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_114.0.5735.248.exe",
      "C:\\your project\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_114.0.5735.16.exe"
    ]
  },
  "standalone": {
    '''
  }
}
```

After this, the end to end tests worked again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use version_main argument as follows:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=116)
```

(116 is the my current installed chrome main version)

see https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/572

But if the your browser is updated you should change the
version_main to the new chrome version
So I am using this method to get the current chrome version and pass it as the version_main value:

1. Install Webdriver Manager for Python: pip install webdriver-manager
2. Use this code:

   import undetected_chromedriver as uc

   from webdriver_manager.core.os_manager import OperationSystemManager,ChromeType
   br_ver = OperationSystemManager().get_browser_version_from_os(ChromeType.GOOGLE)
   version_main=int(br_ver.split('.')[0])
   options = uc.ChromeOptions()
   driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=version_main)