# Incorrect Version of Chromedriver on Undetected-Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Selenium keeps giving me this error which states that I have the incorrect version of Chromedriver, however, I've tried downloading all the recent versions and it still isn't allow me to run Chromedriver. I've downloaded the versions here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
driver.get('https://hangouts.google.com')
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:50803
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 101
Current browser version is 100.0.4896.127
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0139B8F3+2406643]
    Ordinal0 [0x0132AF31+1945393]
    Ordinal0 [0x0121C748+837448]
    Ordinal0 [0x0123C8B3+968883]
    Ordinal0 [0x01235EBB+941755]
    Ordinal0 [0x01235C86+941190]
    Ordinal0 [0x01268EE0+1150688]
    Ordinal0 [0x01268B3A+1149754]
    Ordinal0 [0x01264096+1130646]
    Ordinal0 [0x0123E636+976438]
    Ordinal0 [0x0123F546+980294]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01609612+2498066]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x015FC920+2445600]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01434F2A+579370]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01433D36+574774]
    Ordinal0 [0x01331C0B+1973259]
    Ordinal0 [0x01336688+1992328]
    Ordinal0 [0x01336775+1992565]
    Ordinal0 [0x0133F8D1+2029777]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7632336A+18]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77069902+99]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x770698D5+54]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77131232/8578006

Answer (score 1):

You should update the chrome driver see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773633/11863448) - This has clearly define the issue that you are facing right now.

Comment: I went on the official website and re-downloaded the latest 101 chrome version...