# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I am trying to run this application: https://github.com/flathunters/flathunter

I installed this on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS installation. The package requires Python v3.6+. I am using `pipenv install` and `pipenv shell` as recommended in the [install instructions](https://github.com/flathunters/flathunter#install).

Additionally a chrome-web-driver is required.
I tried to install globally install it on my VPS as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139981/2311074 and point it to `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver`.

I start the script every day for 14 hours. The application works for a couple of days and then it will always exit  with a `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/flathunter/flathunt.py", line 95, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/adam/flathunter/flathunt.py", line 68, in main
    config = Config(config_handle.name)
  File "/home/adam/flathunter/flathunter/config.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.__searchers__ = [CrawlImmobilienscout(self),
  File "/home/adam/flathunter/flathunter/crawl_immobilienscout.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.driver = self.configure_driver(self.driver_executable_path, self.driver_arguments)
  File "/home/adam/flathunter/flathunter/abstract_crawler.py", line 53, in configure_driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/adam/.local/share/virtualenvs/flathunter-SBM5Nxub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/adam/.local/share/virtualenvs/flathunter-SBM5Nxub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/adam/.local/share/virtualenvs/flathunter-SBM5Nxub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/adam/.local/share/virtualenvs/flathunter-SBM5Nxub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/adam/.local/share/virtualenvs/flathunter-SBM5Nxub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=98.0.4758.80)
```

Same issue if I download the chrome driver directly from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

I have chrome and chrome-driver v98 installed.

When I reinstall the machine, it will work again for a few days and then fail at some day forever.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Chrome browser should be installed before starting chrome-web-driver. If it's installed, this https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/ able to detect and download the correct chromedriver for os/browser-version.

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka okay I made I installed chrome correctly, now I get the session error for both, local and global installation. Refactored my question.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the session selenium error is because the selenium browser could not be opened. This is, because everytime the script is started a selenium browser is opened, but if the script is stopped chromedriver is not closed. After a while, you have many chromedriver open:

[image]

And starting a new chromedriver fill fail with "port already in use".

To fix it, you could kill all chromedriver before starting the script.

```
killall chromedriver
```

See also https://github.com/flathunters/flathunter/issues/155