# Beautiful Soup fetch dynamic table data

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have the following code:

```
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2017_standings.html#all_expanded_standings'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(len(soup.findAll('table')))
print(soup.findAll('table'))
```

There are 6 tables on the webpage, but it only returns 4 tables. I tried to use 'html.parser' or 'html5lib' as parsers but did not work either.

Any idea how I can get the Table "expanded standings" from the webpage?

Thanks!

Comment: The rest are loaded by JS.

Comment: What do you mean? do you know how I can access it?

Comment: You can access the rest using selenium.

Answer (score 2):

`requests` can't fetch data that are loaded by `JS`. So, you have to use `selenium`. First install `selenium` via `pip` - `pip install selenium` and download [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.31/) and put the file in your working directory. Then try the following code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2017_standings.html"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print(len(soup.find_all("table")))
print(soup.find("table", {"id": "expanded_standings"}))

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

See `selenium` [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

If you are on `Linux` and get error `Chromedriver executable needs to be in the PATH` then try following these ways - [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130109/cant-use-chrome-driver-for-selenium), [link-2](https://developers.supportbee.com/blog/setting-up-cucumber-to-run-with-Chrome-on-Linux/)