# filenotfound error - chromedriver (web scraping)

Tags: python, selenium, path, selenium-chromedriver

I intend to do web scraping with selenium.

First, I've downloaded chromedriver and place it in right path/folder. Then, wrote the code as below:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe')
```

Why is it still showing the error despite I've checked my path is correct countless times?

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/q/22130109/2986279

Comment: could you please add the error

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you using?

Try without mentioning the extension `.exe`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\chromedriver')
```

One Alternative solution without linking executable path is using `webdriver-manager`. Install it by `pip install webdriver-manager`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the file without the .exe
I use it regularly and none of my scripts have the file extension.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\chromedriver')
```