# Selenium - Chromedriver filenotfound error message

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium to test a webpage I am building.
I downloaded chrome driver and placed the executable in the path below.
I know the path is correct.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Python\chromedriver.exe')
```

What can I do to address this or what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filenotfound error - chromedriver (web scraping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165596/filenotfound-error-chromedriver-web-scraping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the file without the ".exe" extension.
I use chromedriver but I never need to call the extension.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python\chromedriver')
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, idk why that would make a difference but it fixed my issue.